Why is dnf throwing a GLib-ERROR when running under docker
I'm seeing a strange error on docker running Amazon Linux 2023. My host's a Slackware 15 machine running the static versions of the latest docker (26.1) - although the same issue occurred on previous versions.
When I try and do any package management activity on this image, I get an unhelpful GLIB-Error and I don't know what the cause is.
11:34:03:~  $ whoami
richard
11:34:07:~  $ cat /etc/slackware-version 
Slackware 15.0
11:34:09:~  $ docker --version
Docker version 26.1.0, build 9714adc
11:37:54:~  $ docker run -it --rm --entrypoint=/bin/bash public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20
bash-5.2# whoami
whoami
root
bash-5.2# dnf --version
dnf --version

(dnf:7): GLib-ERROR **: 10:40:46.497: file ../glib/gthread-posix.c: line 1340 (g_system_thread_new): error 'Operation not permitted' during 'pthread_create'
Trace/breakpoint trap
bash-5.2# 

I have another Slackware 15 host where this is all working fine but something is different and I can't figure out what. I've encountered this error before on earlier previews of AL2023. The equivalent under the Debian-based Amazon Linux works:
11:42:19:~  $ docker run -it --rm --entrypoint=/bin/bash public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18
bash-4.2# yum --version
yum --version
3.4.3
  Installed: rpm(B-4.11.3-48.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 at 2023-10-20 15:00
  Built    : Amazon Linux at 2023-04-17 16:59
  Committed: Robert Nickel <halfdime@amazon.com> at 2023-04-13

  Installed: yum(B-3.4.3-158.amzn2.0.7.noarch at 2023-10-20 15:02
  Built    : Amazon Linux at 2023-10-18 18:41
  Committed: Nic Anderson <nja@amazon.com> at 2023-10-18
bash-4.2#

